# Formats of input arguments do not match in push_back opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a matrix A of size [2500 x 1]. Now I want to add a [1] to the beginning of the matrix such that the new size of the matrix is [2501 x 1]. Following code I've written:

```
cv::Mat X = cv::Mat::ones(1, 1, CV_64FC1);
cv::Mat imgBlock =  testImage(rect);
        cv::Mat yy = imgBlock.clone();
        cv::Mat xx = yy.reshape(0, 2500);
X.push_back(xx);
```

But when I'm executing the code, opencv is throwing an error as:

> C:\Users\ankitk\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\spt\Release>spt
>   OpenCV Error: Formats of input arguments do not match () in
>   cv::Mat::push_back, file
>   C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp,
>   line 823 –

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not post text as image.  Copy/paste the error message as text into the body of your question.

Comment: C:\Users\ankitk\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\spt\Release>spt
OpenCV Error: Formats of input arguments do not match () in cv::Mat::push_back, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 823

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get that error message is, that the type of `X` and `testImage` do not match. You can only combine matrices of the same type (as it is stated in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-push-back)).

When you run this code

```
std::cout << X.type() << std::endl;
std::cout << imgBlock.type() << std::endl;
```

you will get two different numbers as the output.

You either need to change the type of `X` to match the type of your image or convert `testImage` to `CV_64FC1` before you can append the number.